# Intersection points of a straight line with a closed convex curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

I tried to solve the following problem from Do Carmo. It is very intuitive, but I am having a hard time trying to formalize everything.

Show that if a straight line $L$ meets a closed convex curve $C$, then either $L$ is tangent to $C$ or $L$ intersects $C$ in exactly two points.

Comment: If $L$ intersected $C$ in more than three points, then it would pass outside the interior of $C$. If $L$ intersected in three points, then it could be wiggled slightly so it intersected in four or more points. In either case, what is the implication for $C$?

Comment: It is not clear to me how you can wiggle $L$ so it intersects $C$ in four or more points.

Comment: At at one of them, $L$ is tangent to $C$, so by translating $L$ very slightly in the direction of the outward normal at that tangent point, you will have $L$ intersecting in four points.